# Remove Background Image with Jsoup in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, webview, jsoup

I build apps with WebView and Jsoup for remove elements with unique Id or Class. But i have a problem to remove background image with Jsoup. This is my code with Jsoup for remove background image.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document> {

    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String url = "https://www.mywebsite.com/";

        Document document = null;
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            document.getElementsByAttribute("url(\"https://www.mywebsite.com/assets/style/lapor/images/body-background.jpg\")").remove();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return document;
    } }
```

[image: url that i want to remove]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [JavaDoc](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByAttribute-java.lang.String-) of `getElementsByAttribute` method. It expects a *name of the attribute* as a parameter but you've provided the value of a css property instead. It's obiously wrong and it's not gonna work.

In addition Jsoup is a library for working with HTML. That means you could read, traverse and manipulate a DOM tree of a document but not it's style. I don't think query elements by their style is supported.

However you may fulfill your requirements by:

- Query elements with background image (however you need to know in advance which elements you need to modify).
- Add `style` attribute to them, overriding a `background-image` rule.

For the case you've provided it should work when you replace the line:

```
document.getElementsByAttribute("url(\"https://www.mywebsite.com/assets/style/lapor/images/body-background.jpg\")").remove();
```

... to the following:

```
document.body().attr("style", "background-image: none;")
```